# AngularJS controller not showing data when wrapped in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am using AngularJS and am having issues setting up a function in a controller.

Code in controller

```
$scope.totalUnpaid = 0;
$scope.totalPaid = 0;
$scope.totalHalfDue = 0;
$scope.totalHourDue = 0;
$scope.totalBuisness = 0;
$scope.totalUnpaidSesh = [];
$scope.totalPaidSesh = [];

const getTheSessions = () => {
  adminService.getAllSessions().then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    response.data.forEach(e => e.next_class = e.next_class.substring(0, 10));
    $scope.allSessions = response.data;

    for (var payment in $scope.allSessions) { // iterate through all payments
      if ($scope.allSessions[payment].payment == 'Paid') { // if the person has paid
        $scope.totalPaid++; // count a payment
        $scope.totalPaidSesh.push($scope.trainerSesh[payment]);
      } else { // if the person hasn't paid
        $scope.totalUnpaid++; // count a non-payment
        $scope.totalUnpaidSesh.push($scope.allSessions[payment]);
      }
    }

    for (var next_session in $scope.totalUnpaidSesh) {
      if ($scope.totalUnpaidSesh[next_session].next_session == '30_Minute') {
        $scope.totalHalfDue = $scope.totalHalfDue + 25;
      } else if ($scope.unpaidSesh[next_session].next_session == 'Hour_Session') {
        $scope.totalHourDue = $scope.totalHourDue + 50;
      }
    }

    $scope.totalBuisness = $scope.totalHalfDue + $scope.totalHourDue;

  });
};
```

For some reason I cant get the data I ask for to show up. If I console log in the service I can see the data that should show but it disappears in the controller.

However when I get rid of the scope and go directly to the service like this

```
  $scope.totalUnpaid = 0;
  $scope.totalPaid = 0;
  $scope.totalHalfDue = 0;
  $scope.totalHourDue = 0;
  $scope.totalBuisness = 0;
  $scope.totalUnpaidSesh = [];
  $scope.totalPaidSesh = [];


  adminService.getAllSessions().then((response) => {

        console.log(response);
        response.data.forEach(e => e.next_class = e.next_class.substring(0, 10));
        $scope.allSessions = response.data;

        for (var payment in $scope.allSessions) { // iterate through all payments
          if ($scope.allSessions[payment].payment == 'Paid') { // if the person has paid
            $scope.totalPaid++; // count a payment
            $scope.totalPaidSesh.push($scope.trainerSesh[payment]);
          } else { // if the person hasn't paid
            $scope.totalUnpaid++; // count a non-payment
            $scope.totalUnpaidSesh.push($scope.allSessions[payment]);
          }
        }

        for (var next_session in $scope.totalUnpaidSesh) {
          if ($scope.totalUnpaidSesh[next_session].next_session == '30_Minute') {
            $scope.totalHalfDue = $scope.totalHalfDue + 25;
          } else if ($scope.unpaidSesh[next_session].next_session == 'Hour_Session') {
            $scope.totalHourDue = $scope.totalHourDue + 50;
          }
        }

        $scope.totalBuisness = $scope.totalHalfDue + $scope.totalHourDue;

  });
```

I get the data.

Why does this work but when I attach the method

```
const getTheSessions = () => {
```

it doesn't?

Comment: Where is getTheSessions being called? Is that code that should happen upon initialization of the controller? Which version of angularJS are you using? So many questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$ngInit` life-cycle hook:

```
this.$ngInit = getTheSessions;

̶c̶o̶n̶s̶t̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶T̶h̶e̶S̶e̶s̶s̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶=̶ ̶(̶)̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶{̶
function getTheSessions() {
  adminService.getAllSessions().then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    response.data.forEach(e => e.next_class = e.next_class.substring(0, 10));
    $scope.allSessions = response.data;

    //Other code
  });
}
```